# Domain change - So how to update google properties?

Tags: google-analytics, domains

Recently one of my clients changes the domain name and I am facing some issues with changing the new domain in Google tools like search console and Analytics GA4 and AdWords.

Option 1 : Go ahead and create new properties all for a new domain.
Option 2 : While switching domains they have the same code at the backend so in GA4 there is the same code it is processing. I am getting data. So should I keep it as it is or should I need to create a new property?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to verify the new domain in Google Search Console, but Analytics should keep running and processing data for the site. There are settings in Analytics that may prevent that, but only if Analytics had default settings changed.

I would keep running the same analytics code.

Adwords will need new ads or redirects for the old URLs.

Comment: Unlike UA, the ability to filter traffic data by hostname in GA4 is much more difficult.